# difference between default and Full Processing

Tags: sql-server, ssms, olap, cube, olap-cube

I'm trying to understand how processing a cube in default mode vs. a full process is different for SQL Server Olap cubes. This article gives a brief description of each

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/process-database-table-or-partition-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_process_db

A full process is essentially truncating all the data and rebuilding it from scratch from the ground up with the data that is present in the source tables. This is easy enough to grasp.

However, for the default mode(which at this point I'm pretty sure is what we do on a nightly basis to ensure our cube is up to date) is described as:

> Detects the process state of database objects, and performs processing necessary to deliver unprocessed or partially processed objects to a fully processed state. Data for empty tables and partitions is loaded; hierarchies, calculated columns, and relationships are built or rebuilt (recalculated).

Can someone explain how the process state of a fact partition or a dimension is determined? As our ETL produces new data each day that data is ingested into the cube and the processing takes 1.5 hours. If I fully reprocess the same cube it can take 6+ hours. If all partitions and dimensions are being reprocessed using the default method then what difference makes the default method so much briefer than the Full process method? How is the procedure determining what objects are in an incomplete or partially processed state?

Answer (score 1):

For modern tabular models "Default" maps to "automatic" [TMSL Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/refresh-command-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allversions).

If a partition's State is [Ready](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssas-t/81badb81-31a8-482b-ae16-5fc9d8291d9e) automatic refresh takes no action.  And the passage of time does not change the partition's State.  If it was successfully refreshed it will stay Ready, and an "automatic" refresh will take no action.